# Minecraft: testfor not full health

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a command block linked to a timer with the following command:

`kill @p[score_health_min=1,score_health_max=19]`

I also have a second command block with this command, triggered earlier when the player starts the game:

`scoreboard objectives add health health`

When I slightly injure myself (to a health of under 19), I don't get killed! **Why not? Do I have any errors in my commands?** Thanks for any help that anyone can supply!

Comment: I'm sorry, what's your question?

Comment: Why do I not get killed when I injure myself?

Comment: Have you prefaced the command with a slash?

Comment: @Chippies A slash is not needed in command block code. If a slash is not provided, it is added when the command gets run without being shown.

Comment: @Chippies In a command block you don't have to preface the command with a slash.

Answer (score 5):

Try using this line instead and make sure your timer is always ticking:
`kill @p[score_health=19,score_health_min=1]`

Right now you're checking for `score_XYZ_max`, which doesn't exist as a target selector argument. You need to check for `score_XYZ` instead, which *is* checking for a maximum.

[Source](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/2238847-command-block-help-testfor-low-health/)

Comment: IIRC, `score_name_max` isn't even a thing, nor does it have the functionality you have stated; it's just called `score_name`.

Comment: I'm not sure where you see `score_name_max` mentioned, but even if `score_health_max` doesn't have the functionality I said it does, it doesn't change the validity of my answer.

Comment: OP's command has `score_health_max`, you say that this is always 20, I'm saying that it doesn't exist at all. Doesn't affect the actual solution, although it does affect the reasoning and may trip people up in the future.

Comment: Edited my answer to avoid confusion.